# Parsing the XML and add it as Key Value pair

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, xml-parsing, windows-phone

I have a document like this:

```
<dict>
<key> 1</key>
<string>AAA</string>
<key> 2</key>
<string>BBB</string>
<key> 3</key>
<string>CCC</string>
<key> 4</key>
<string>DDD</string>
</dict>
```

I am parsing like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Root.Elements("dict")
                   .ToDictionary(c => (string)c.Element("key"),
                                 c => (string)c.Element("string"));

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dict)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Key and Valkue is ", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
```

But its not printing the values , and also if the user passes key as Line 1 i need to get its corresponding value ?

In Java we use hashMap to acheive this , i new to c#, how to acheive this ? what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Although your xml seems to be valid, it is not good structured. You can not count on the order of elements, So `Line 1, DDD` pair is also valid.

Comment: @L.B But in JAVA i am able to do it using HashMap perfectly , but how do we acheive this in c# ?Can you suggest me to try something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xmlDict = XDocument.Load(filename).Root.Element("dict");
var dict = xmlDict.Elements("key")
           .Zip(xmlDict.Elements("string"), (k, s) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.Value, s.Value))
           .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

PS: Don't forget, as I said in the comments, *you should not count on the order of elements*

Comment: can you please have a look at it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044034/overriding-methods-from-library-project