# Overriding methods from Library Project

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, class-library

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application.

I  have a Windows Phone Class Library project(Called Base) and Windows Phone App(called child).

In my Base project i have a class which has methods and static variables.

Eg:

```
 Class Settings
    {

    public static string AppName = "Base";

    public virtual List<String> TabDetails()
            {
                List<String> TabDetails = new List<string>();
                helpTabDetails.Add("AAA");
                helpTabDetails.Add("BBB");
                return helpTabDetails;
            }

    }
```

Now in my child app i am just linking this class (by pressing ALT when we are dragging and dropping we can link the class image etc ... i am not adding a reference in th references folder).

Now in my Base those were the default settings of my app, but i want to change those settings if REQUIRED, if i DONT REQUIRE to change then the default settings should be applied to my child app.

NOTE: My Base will have all the class related to my app, but my child app will only contain the app specific settings class.

How can i acheive this ?

**EDIT**

More specific:

In my Base:

```
 Class Demo : Settings
    {

    AppName = "XYX"

   override TabDetails() and give new implemntation

    }
```

Now in my Child app if i am OVERRIDING these static variables or methods then it should pick those values, but how to acheive that ?

Comment: if "REQUIRED"? at compile time or run-time. normally if you use file linking, then you use `#ifdef`'s to provide different implementations for different targets. This will only be for compile time ofc.

Comment: if you want your check at run-time, then just make the function in your lib project expect an interface for settings. Then either pass the interface or pass null to then use defaults from your application project at runtime. If you use IoC then it becomes even more simple. but concept still holds.

Comment: @Viv i did not get your point, can you please show me with an example

Comment: ok just saw your edit, that wasn't wht i was thinking you're after. well if you override `TabDetails()` in the `Demo` class any object of `Demo` class when it calls `TabDetails()` should return the overriden method data. Isn't that what you're getting right now or have i still not got what your problem is

Comment: Yes it will give me , but the Implmentation is from BASE and not from CHILD , i want to do the same thing in child app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48488/discussion-between-viv-and-user2056563)

Comment: @Viv Hey sorry i couldnt get back to you, i have few more doubts, ping me when you are free

Comment: Hey, what is it you're having trouble with. Just join the same chat channel again from the previous comment and type it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a long chat, Finally got to get the requirement the OP was looking for.

In simple terms:

- He had an interface called `AppSettings`
- A class called `DefaultSettings` implements this interface
- Another class called `CustomSettings` could or could not be present in the project which also would implement the `AppSettings` interface

Question is how to check and use `ChildSettings` if present else use `DefaultSettings`

**Solution**:

Use reflection and check for the type's presence and if available to use it.

```
AppSettings appSettings;
var customSettingsType = Type.GetType("POCChild.ChildSettings");
if (customSettingsType == null)
  appSettings = new DefaultSettings();
else
  appSettings = (AppSettings)Activator.CreateInstance(customSettingsType);

Debug.WriteLine(appSettings.getAppName());
```

where `"POCChild.ChildSettings"` is the `Namespace.ClassName`

Comment: Please ping me when you are free

Comment: If you are free just have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094143/macros-in-prefix-pch-file-equivalent-in-wp8

Comment: @user2056563 Sorry I'm tied up for a while. Do try to not post other topic questions as looking for help on another thread. It helps keep information on a page relevant to the main question. If you've posted a question, I'm sure someone would spot it and offer you help eventually while hopefully you're trying to solve it yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, override property values instead of functions. Use the following code in your `Base` class:

```
class Settings
{
    public virtual string AppName
    {
        get { return "Base"; }
    }

    public virtual List<String> TabDetails()
        {
            List<String> TabDetails = new List<string>();
            helpTabDetails.Add("AAA");
            helpTabDetails.Add("BBB");
            return helpTabDetails;
        }

} 

class Demo : Settings
{
    public override string AppName
    {
        get { return "XYX"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about in child class

Comment: `Demo` class is a child class of `Settings` which you place in your app.

Comment: Ok in that case say i have a class A in Base which extends Settings will i be able to override its values ? and also if i dont override it  will it take default values ?

Comment: please see here as well , i found a soultion but its not complete its buggy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060464/overriding-methods-values-in-app-xaml-cs