# Overriding methods values in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, class-library

I am working on Windows 8 Phone application,I have 2 things here one is Library project and other is normal app,Let me first explain my code:

**In Library project**

```
    class A
    {
      public static string empName ="ABC";
      public static int empID = 123;

      public virtual List<string> ListOfEmployees()
      {
           List<string> empList = new List<string>
           empList.Add("Adam");
           empList.Add("Eve");
           return empList;
      }

}
```

I have referenced the library project in my child project, My child and Library project are in 2 different solution.

**In Child application**

```
class Properties : A
{

 public void setValues(){
       empName ="ASDF"
       ListOfEmployees();
}
  public override List<string> ListOfEmployees()
          {
               List<string> empList = new List<string>
               empList.Add("Kyla");
               empList.Add("Sophia");
               return empList;
          }
      }
```

Now in every Child Application we `App.xaml.cs` which is the entry point of each project.

In this `App.xaml.cs` file i am creating an object of this `Properties and calling setValues method.`

What i see here is only static variables values are overridden but the methods are not overridden.Why so ? am i doing anything wrong here ?

I get the ASDF and list with Adam and Eve as output

But i need ASDF and list with Kyla and Sophia as output.

How to achieve this ?

**EDIT**

How i am using these values:

In my Base :

```
class XYZ : A

    {
      // now i can get empName as weel as the ListOfEmployees()
       string employeeName = null;

       public void bind()
       {
         employeeName = empName ; 
         ListOfEmployees(); // here is the bug where i always get Adam and Eve and not the Kyla and sophia
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand, you want to call overriden values from your project *in* your library.

You cannot do that with classical C# mechanisms, for that you need dependency injection. Something along these lines:

```
// library
public interface IA
{
    List<string> ListOfEmployees();
}

public class ABase : IA
{
    public virtual List<string> ListOfEmployees() {}
}


public static class Repository
{
    private static IA _a;

    public static IA A
    {
        get { return _a = _a ?? new ABase(); }
        set { _a = value; }
    }
}

// in your app

class Properties : ABase
{
    public override List<string> ListOfEmployees() { /* ... */ }
}

Repository.A = new Properties();
```

Comment: yes, in my child app i can do this and give implementation, but in my base i need to have default impl as well

Comment: Well, your complex requirements require a complex solution. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Change the override keyword to new and you'll get the behaviour you're after. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) for more information on when to use which.

Comment: code which i have shown in my question is same, but make sure that you try with library project and normal application

Comment: look at this output // TestCars1
// ----------
// Four wheels and an engine.
// Standard transportation.
// ----------
// Four wheels and an engine.
// Standard transportation.
// ----------
// Four wheels and an engine.
// Carries seven people.
// ----------
in the link which you gave me, you  will come to know