# Parsing Dictionary within a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

i have this xml:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Johnson</key>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>4525434</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Neil Johnson</string>
        <key>firstname</key>
        <string>neil</string>
        </dict>
    <key>Adam</key>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>481689</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Andrew Adam</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

How to parse this and display the data based on key `Johnson and Adam`

I tried this:

```
var xmlDict = doc.Root.Element("dict");
Dictionary<string, string> dict = xmlDict.Elements("key")
           .Zip(xmlDict.Elements("string"), (k, s) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.Value, s.Value))
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

But this will only add the items to inner Dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is nested, so you need `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` to store it. Following query should do the trick:

```
var dict = xmlDict.Elements("key")
           .Zip(xmlDict.Elements("dict"), (k, v) => new { k, v })
           .ToDictionary(
                x => (string)x.k,
                x => x.v.Elements("key")
                        .Zip(x.v.Elements("string"), (k, v) => new { k, v })
                        .ToDictionary(y => (string)y.k, y => (string)y.v));
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, i have one more query if you can please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060464/overriding-methods-values-in-app-xaml-cs

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948975/parse-xml-with-same-key-values